# How should I expose a list from a ViewModel using reactive UI?

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

how should I expose a list from a ViewModel using reactive UI?

I want a grid in the view to bind to the list.

Should I use ObservableCollection or something in the reactiveUI framework?

```
public class BooksViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    ObservableCollection<Book> Books{ get; set; }  
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `ReactiveList` class, which is everything `ObservableCollection` is, plus a lot of other cool stuff. If your list of books will never change once you create the initial list, you can use a simple `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

**Depends on your requirements.**

Do you really need `ReactiveObject` to listen to events that you **only care about**?

If no, the use cases I can think of for you to listen is for simple `Add, Edit, Delete,` which `ObservableCollection` already provides by default. So just use `ObservableCollection`

But if you don't care in the built in changes that `ObservableCollection` provides and you only care about `Subscribing` to certain events that you want then I'll use `ReactiveObject`. Also, if I need other objects to do A when B is published.

Don't complicate your `ViewModel` too much in the beginning. Bring `ReactiveUI` when you see a use case where you really need it.